# Problem in push image of docker in registry

Tags: docker, deployment, gitlab, docker-registry

i have a problem with deploy in my gitlab registry, this is my gitlab-ci

```
build_and_push:
  stage: Push
  image: docker:latest
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "dist/"
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG .
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_TOKEN" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG
```

return:

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logged into one registry (`$CI_REGISTRY`):

```
echo "$CI_REGISTRY_TOKEN" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
```

But then push to a different one (`$DOCKER_REGISTRY`):

```
docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG
```

You need to update your build to login to the registry you have access to push, and then push to that registry.